# How to get a Regex for entire sequence of numbers in a string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to write a regex to extract an entire number from a string that is not proceeded or followed by a number?

For example, in a string "1 is not 10 and also not 100!" --> how do I write a regex to match 1 (only once at the beginning of the string) 10 (only once) and 100 (also only once). My issue is that if I use something like `[0-9]+`, then it can extract 1 three times and 10 twice. Any idea how to limit that?

Comment: Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The regex you specified `[0-9]+` correctly matches every number only once.

Comment: What do you mean by “it can extract 1 three times and 10 twice”?

Comment: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/AEnoiL/1/codegen?language=java) example

Comment: Need clarification as it does not depict clear intent. However, regex also allows the number of character matches so instead of + you can specify number by writing like: [0-9]{1}. Again, provide sufficient details to understand use case clearly

Comment: `[0-9]+` matches "10" only once. How are you extracting your matches? What is your exact regex?

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that if I use something like [0-9]+, then it can extract 1 three times and 10 twice. Any idea how to limit that?

That's just not how regexes work, though:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+"); // \\d is the same as [0-9], just, more common
Matcher m = p.matcher("1 is not 10 and also not 100!");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

The above will print 1, 10, and 100.

Modifiers like `+` are, by default, **greedy** (that's a technical term): They will match as much as they can. You can even get a non-greedy variant here (`+?` and `*?` are the non-greedy variants of `+` and `*`) which match as little as they can.

If you run the same thing with `+?`, you'd get 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, and 0.